# Why is MySQL2 execute command returning a buffer in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using `mysql2/promise` to run some sql queries. Here is my query:

```
requests = await conn.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE (requester=? AND acceptor=?) OR (requester=? AND acceptor=?)',
    [ 1, 2, 2, 1]
);
```

When I run this command I get the following results:

```
{
"message": [
    [],
    [
        {
            "_buf": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    1,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    3,
                    77,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    3,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    75,
                    0,
                    0,
                    3,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    11,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    73,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    12,
                    63,
                    0,
                    19,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    7,
                    128,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    6,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "_clientEncoding": "utf8",
            "_catalogLength": 3,
            "_catalogStart": 10,
            "_schemaLength": 7,
            "_schemaStart": 14,
            "_tableLength": 15,
            "_tableStart": 22,
            "_orgTableLength": 15,
            "_orgTableStart": 38,
            "_orgNameLength": 9,
            "_orgNameStart": 64,
            "characterSet": 224,
            "encoding": "utf8",
            "name": "requester",
            "columnLength": 1024,
            "columnType": 253,
            "flags": 20483,
            "decimals": 0
        },
        {
            "_buf": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    1,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    3,
                    77,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    3,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    75,
                    0,
                    0,
                    3,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    11,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    73,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    12,
                    63,
                    0,
                    19,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    7,
                    128,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    6,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "_clientEncoding": "utf8",
            "_catalogLength": 3,
            "_catalogStart": 91,
            "_schemaLength": 7,
            "_schemaStart": 95,
            "_tableLength": 15,
            "_tableStart": 103,
            "_orgTableLength": 15,
            "_orgTableStart": 119,
            "_orgNameLength": 8,
            "_orgNameStart": 144,
            "characterSet": 224,
            "encoding": "utf8",
            "name": "acceptor",
            "columnLength": 1024,
            "columnType": 253,
            "flags": 20491,
            "decimals": 0
        },
        {
            "_buf": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    1,
                    0,
                    0,
                    1,
                    3,
                    77,
                    0,
                    0,
                    2,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    9,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    101,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    3,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    75,
                    0,
                    0,
                    3,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    8,
                    97,
                    99,
                    99,
                    101,
                    112,
                    116,
                    111,
                    114,
                    12,
                    224,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    253,
                    11,
                    80,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    73,
                    0,
                    0,
                    4,
                    3,
                    100,
                    101,
                    102,
                    7,
                    67,
                    111,
                    109,
                    114,
                    97,
                    100,
                    101,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    15,
                    102,
                    114,
                    105,
                    101,
                    110,
                    100,
                    95,
                    114,
                    101,
                    113,
                    117,
                    101,
                    115,
                    116,
                    115,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    7,
                    99,
                    114,
                    101,
                    97,
                    116,
                    101,
                    100,
                    12,
                    63,
                    0,
                    19,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    7,
                    128,
                    4,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    5,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0,
                    5,
                    0,
                    0,
                    6,
                    254,
                    0,
                    0,
                    34,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "_clientEncoding": "utf8",
            "_catalogLength": 3,
            "_catalogStart": 170,
            "_schemaLength": 7,
            "_schemaStart": 174,
            "_tableLength": 15,
            "_tableStart": 182,
            "_orgTableLength": 15,
            "_orgTableStart": 198,
            "_orgNameLength": 7,
            "_orgNameStart": 222,
            "characterSet": 63,
            "encoding": "binary",
            "name": "created",
            "columnLength": 19,
            "columnType": 7,
            "flags": 1152,
            "decimals": 0
        }
    ]
]
}
```

What is this? I thought I would get something like `requests[0].column_name`. Am I doing the query wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `await conn.execute` will only return the fields of the table if there are 0 results.

Therefore, you have to specify rows as a variable in order to get the empty array of rows as follows:

```
const [rows, fields] = await conn.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE (requester=? AND acceptor=?) OR (requester=? AND acceptor=?)',
    [ 1, 2, 2, 1]
);
```

Now `rows` will have the rows returned in the query and `fields` is an array of fields (the buffer that is being returned in the question).

Comment: Makes sense - sort of. What would I need `fields` for then?

Comment: `console.log(rows[0] // BinaryRow { 'COUNT(*)': 300024 }` Why `BinaryRow`? Why not just get us directly to the results there, `'COUNT'`, in this case? Seems like too much nesting and obfuscation of the desired results, no?